# Using sendRedirect inside a servlet forwarded with request dispatcher

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I have a filter that implements a custom convention for loading servlets and JSPs. In that convention I am using the following code to include the servlet:

```
servletContext
    .getRequestDispatcher( uriDispatcherLocator.getServletLocation( uri ) )
    .include( request, response );
```

and the following code to include the JSP (in the same filter):

```
servletContext
    .getRequestDispatcher( "/index.jsp" )
    .include( request, response );
```

Everything works fine, the servlet executes, then it includes the JSP and some irrelevant custom rules take place.
As you can see, at the very moment I include a servlet with request dispatcher **I cannot send an http header response to the client**.
The problem is that I want the servlet to have full control of the response as if it was called from inside the filter (because the filter will do nothing else than dinamically mapping the servlets according to their respective Class/JSP location in the project file system).
I can use `.forward()` instead of `.include()`, but if I do I will not be able to include a JSP after the servlet has been executed.

So, how would I allow the servlet to execute the code below when being included through a filter via RequestDispatcher interface?

```
response.sendRedirect( "/somePath" );
```

No Javascript hacks, I am willing to send the proper HTTP response from the server to make the browser behave correctly.

--

EDIT:
In other words:

I want to change the headers sent to the client from INSIDE an included servlet by using RequestDispatcher, but the docs states:

```
The included servlet cannot change the response status code or set headers; any attempt to make a change is ignored.
```

Comment: You can't render jsps if your going to send a redirect. I'm probably misunderstanding what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: You could throw an exception in the servlet to indicate the filter to redirect instead. Not the most elegant solution but at least the decition to redirect could stay in the servlet...

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am including the servlet content into the response. I want to include the servlet, be able to manipulate the headers and include the jsp with the filter.

Comment: @SirRotN I dont want just to redirect. Sometimes it should be needed to manipulate the headers somehow so I cant create one exception type for each behavior (although it kind of make a little sense)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **Filter** includes your servlet

```
servletContext
    .getRequestDispatcher( uriDispatcherLocator.getServletLocation( uri ) )
    .include( request, response );
```

Your **Servlet** indicates it wants to redirect

```
request.setAttribute ("sendRedirect", "/some/path");
```

or, wishes to **add** one or more response **headers**

```
Map<String, String> respHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();
respHeaders.put("Expires", "0");
respHeaders.put("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
request.setAttribute("respHeaders", respHeaders);
```

Your **Filter** checks for these special requests

```
Map<String, String> respHeaders =
                   (Map<String, String>) request.getAttribute("respHeaders");
for (String key : respHeaders.keySet()) {
    response.setHeader(key, respHeaders.get(key)); // set response headers
}

String sendRedirect;
if ((sendRedirect = (String) request.getAttribute("sendRedirect")) != null) {
    response.sendRedirect(sendRedirect); // redirect the client
}
```

**EDIT**: Perhaps some of your servlets are already driving the flow and setting response headers when called from outside an include. But, there's no way to reuse them as is. You can't simply include them and expect the same behaviour because the goal of a RequestDispatcher#include() is to provide for server-side includes (SSI) only.

Hence, we do not find any overloaded methods (or any setters that could modify this behaviour) in the API. If you want to include such servlets and retain their behaviour (like redirects) you would have to pass them a hint that they're running under an *include* context and so should submit their response requests.

```
request.setAttribute ("includeContext", true);
```

Comment: It is a simple and very good solution. Unfortunately it requires an additional control which goes beyond the spec. I am looking maybe for a solution that makes use of some API that allows such behavior without having to create a customized implementation, if exists of course.

Comment: The solution actually abides by the spec completely. The spec treats the web component being included as a "guest" i.e. it can't direct the flow and any such attempts would be rightly ignored (instead of an exception to possibly allow an include for any servlet that you may have). The spec states that only the host web component (the one doing an include) would be in complete control of the flow as well as what response headers are sent over to the client.